# how to convert usbmon capture to libpcap format

Tags: ubuntu, usb, wireshark

I have captured the usb raw data in linux embedded system using USBMon:

## cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1u > /tmp/1.mon.out

tcpdump or dumpcap or TShark is not installed in Embedded system. hence I dump/save the raw output of usbmon to a file.

And for offline analysis, how to decode the usbmon-trace(1.mon.out) in Linux System (e.g. Ubuntu desktop) to view in Wireshark?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm not able to find a clear answer of how to dump USB data on an embedded system which don't have high end software such as wireshark. I think there must be more people who would make use of this